# OKHttp3: how to retry another IP address if one is unreachable

Tags: okhttp

does OkHttp3 support the following case:

- x.x.x.x myapp.com
- y.y.y.y myapp.com

we have two IPs for one hostname, looks like OkHttpClient always retry the first IP address instead of trying another available IP address.

does retryOnConnectionFailure(true) support this? from the doc, by default it should support this?

Configure this client to retry or not when a connectivity problem is encountered. By default, this client silently recovers from the following problems:

- Unreachable IP addresses. If the URL’s host has multiple IP
  addresses, failure to reach any individual IP address doesn’t fail
  the overall request. This can increase availability of multi-homed
  services.

  Stale pooled connections. The ConnectionPool reuses sockets to
  decrease request latency, but these connections will occasionally
  time out.

  Unreachable proxy servers. A ProxySelector can be used to attempt
  multiple proxy servers in sequence, eventually falling back to a
  direct connection.

  Set this to false to avoid retrying requests when doing so is
  destructive. In this case the calling application should do its own
  recovery of connectivity failures.

Answer (score 1):

OkHttp will try both in sequence.

Comment: but in our test, we saw it did retry the first IP which is not reachable and didn't try the second IP which is available.   what could be the cause? should I call retryOnConnectionFailure(true) explicitly?

Comment: I did see the dns respond with
 3663 16.544083 192.168.3.4 192.168.3.234 DNS 149 Standard query response 0xa986 A smf.xxx.com A 100.66.31.25 A 1.1.1.1 NS dns-primary.xxx.com A 100.70.181.24
but it only did retransmission on the first ip 1.1.1.1, which is the fake ip.  but never see it try to connect to 100.70.181.24, I did set retryOnConnectionFailure(true).

Comment: can someone answer my question?
I did see some code to loop the IP address which retrieved by dns lookup():

Comment: Do you have any idea in which java class in okhttp3 package, okhttp will try both IP address?